# Laravel 5.2 How to authenticate with a real mysql database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new with laravel, I read the documentation of laravel, but I don't know how I make an authentication with a real mysql database.
I mean, I see that there is a php migration command, but it makes a table in php and not in my database right ? 
Actually, I have a mysql database with a user table with login and password.
I'm lost with this framework, because I never used a php framework.

Thanks !!

**Edit :**
Excuse me, I misspoke and my problem has evolved, how did you to authenticate with a user table already exists in the database by using the Authentication service?

Comment: You need to configure your db connection in .env file. Then Laravel 5.2 can create auth for you `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 3):

in **.env** or **config>database.php** you can set your database and related database connections configurations 
after that create migrations and run them it will create database tables in your database as per your **.env** or **config>database.php** database configurations.

Comment: Don't use `database.php`. Use `.env` instead

Comment: thank you for your reply, I set my database but If I already have a table user in my database, is the migration command will delete my table ?

Comment: Doesn't deserve a downvote, you can use `config/database.php` or `.env`

Comment: @haakym sure, but if u will share 1 connection accross all team, its not cool.

Comment: drop your table and run your migrations. @KhoyaDev

Comment: @GONG i have changed my answer

Comment: Yes, `.env` is the preferred way and avoids such issues, but the application relies on `config/database.php` to establish the connection. It's probably worth mentioning both.

Comment: @HimanshuRaval ok, be careful from sharing bad practices. Removed Downvote.

Comment: thank you all ! I have another question, how I say to the migration command the columns I want ?

Comment: Ok, but I have not tested yet because I read the literature that you cited

Comment: I have an issue, I launch `php artisan migration user` and it made a file in migration folder, but It not created  the table user in my database. So I remove manually the file and I launch `php artisan migration --create user` but now I have this message : ' laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream'

Comment: Give read-write permissions to your app/storage folder @KhoyaDev

Comment: It's already in read-write. I think I'll make a new laravel project no ?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage` or `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` and then try

Comment: thank you it works, but I launch ` php artisan make:migration user --create user` but the user table is not created in my database

Comment: use `php artisan migrate`

Comment: It doesn't work because, I did not notice that my table user was created, so I have a user table so it's good thanks ! Another question, how I did to tell to laravel that I have an existing tables in my database, because I already have many tables with constraints. Eg: Before I removed my table user in my database, I also had a table userRole

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114347/discussion-between-khoyadev-and-himanshu-raval).

Comment: in migration use `Schema::hasTable('mytable');` to check if table existrs...if there is then update it or drop it as per your needs .Please accept answer if its helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to read again Laravel documentations.

Try the following.

1. Make sure you have a database create in your MySql.
2. Check again your .env for: database_host, database_name, database_user, database_password - make sure you have the right
3. Try bellow code on your route.php

   Route::get('/', function () {
       if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
   {
      echo "Yes! successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
   }
   });
4. If above is successful your migration should work.

Comment: Thank you, this is well explained !